# Facebook open graph redirect when clicking on shared box from website

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Good morning, I'm Gabriele from Italy, nice to meet you all.
I have a problem with Facebook open graph. We have a 2 pages wordpress website: in the first one there is a mail chimp form to fill to join a sort of competition. When you subscribe to the form you are redirected to page 2 with congratulations etc..
In this second page there is a sharing element so you can share that you have joined the competition. I need that the box you visualize when you share page 2 on fb do not send you to that page but to the first one. So in the second page  I set this open graph tags but it always redirect to page 2:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="the first page I want to share, not the second">
<meta property="og:title" content="bla bla">
<meta property="og:image" content="image url">
<meta property="og:description" content="bla bla">
<meta property="og:locale" content="it_IT">
```

Can someone please help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Either put a simple JavaScript redirect into the code of the second page (the Facebook scraper does not care for JavaScript, so this will only redirect human visitors following the link), or implement a server-side redirect (the latter will need an exception for the Facebook scraper; can be recognized by its User-Agent.)

Answer (score 0):

Pointing the `og:url` from the second page to the first one should work, as long as:

- The Facebook crawler can read this second page and see this og:url. If this results page access is restricted (i.e. to the logged in user that caused it) it would not work
- The first page has a correct `og:url` pointing to itself.

You can use the Sharing debugger to verify if the crawler is being able to see your changes, and also to force it to refresh any cache it may have from a previous version: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/